# precompile assets in rails is falling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just deploy my code to heroku and there are two files missing.

```
javascripts/application.js 
stylesheets/application.css
```

I am trying to precompile the assets.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and I am getting the following error.

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Rails
/Users/username/projects/project/Rakefile:33:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Does it have a file/line reference?

Comment: /Users/username/projects/project/Rakefile:33:in `<top (required)>'